# Server Node.js: All external connections start hanging

Tags: node.js, sockets, request, connection-timeout

node.js script starts the server(**function:startServer**) and waits for clients, then according to the client's request script parses several sites (**function:wget**) and gives sorted results.

At a load of 50 requests per second , 5-10 seconds after all external connections to the sites start hanging, connections are dropped on timeout(Error: socket hang up)
, but it does not change anything, after that everything is just hanging.

**Function start server:**

```
function startServer(cfg, cb) {
var server = http.createServer();
server.listen(cfg.port, cfg.hostname);

server.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.setNoDelay();
});

server.on('clientError', function (exception) {
    console.log('Server: clientError', exception);
});

server.on('request', function (request, response) {

    request.socket.on('error',function(err){
        console.log('socket error: ', err);
    });

    cb(request, response);
});

server.on('error', function (err) {
    console.error('Server:', err);
});
```

}

**Get page**

```
function wget(options, onResult) {

var prot = options.port == 443 ? https : http;

var req = prot.request(options, function (res) {

    res.setEncoding('utf8');

    var output = '';

    res.on('data', function (chunk) {
        output += chunk;
    });

    res.on('end', function () {
        onResult(null, res, output);

    });
}); 

req.on('error', function (err) {
    onResult(err, null, null);
});

req.on('socket', function (socket) {
    socket.setTimeout(3000);
    socket.on('timeout', function () {
        req.abort();
    });
});

req.end();
```

}

**Multi request**

```
var tmp = [];
http.globalAgent.maxSockets  = 50000;
https.globalAgent.maxSockets = 50000;

_config.providers.forEach(function (provider) {

    tmp.push(function (callback) {

        var opt = provider;
        opt.agent = false;
        //        opt.host = ''; // from provider.host
        //        opt.port = ''; // from provider.port
        wget(opt, function (error, resp, body) {
            var ok = null;
            if (!error) {
                ok = {provider: provider, data: body.toString()};
            } else {
                console.log(error, opt.host + opt.path);
            }
            callback(null, ok);
        });

    });

});

// start requests to providers
_async.parallel(tmp, function (err, results) {
    // .. code..
    serverResponse.end('results');
});
```

**Server OS FreeBSD 9.2**

**node: v0.10.22**

**On the server all possible limits are increased**

> ulimit -a
>
> socket buffer size       (bytes, -b) unlimited
>
> core file size          (blocks, -c) unlimited
>
> data seg size           (kbytes, -d) 33554432
>
> file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
>
> max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
>
> max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
>
> open files                      (-n) 200000
>
> pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 1
>
> stack size              (kbytes, -s) 524288
>
> cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
>
> max user processes              (-u) 9000
>
> virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
>
> swap size               (kbytes, -w) unlimited

*thanks a lot for any help*